# spacing between two floating point values in a normalized system?

Tags: numerical-methods

Let x be a given nonzero floating-point number in a normalized system, and let y be an adjacent floating-point number, also non-zero.

a) What's the minimum possible spacing between x and y?
b) What's the maximum possible spacing between x and y?

I know Floating-point number system is characterized by four integers,

x = `+/- (d_0 + d1/B + d2/B + ... + d_(p-1)/B^(p-1)*B^E`, where

0 <= d_i, <= B - 1, i = 0,...,p-1 and L <= E <= U

I can't seem to correlate the relationship between the equation I have and the minimum/maximum possible spacing possible between the two adjacent FP numbers. Help please!

Comment: This does not belong in a math forum.  Unless you define all those terms you use.  Instead I guess it belongs in a computer forum.  Besides that: when you ask a question here you must show your own work before you can expect us to also work on it.

Comment: I tried to give a little more definition.. Sorry about that, but this class I am taking is a math class..